# SQL: How can I use CTE instead of self join? How it affects performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

An interviewer gave me below data and asked me to print employee id, employee Name, Manager Name, and salary. I was also asked to print salary of employee in descending order for each manager

```
EmpId   Name    MgrId   Salary
1       James   7       10000
2       Nick    7       11000
3       David   7       10000
4       Stephen 8       12000
5       Maddy   8       11000
6       Auck    9       11000
7       Sydney  9       21000
8       Athens  10      22000
9       Irene   10      22000
10      Thomas  NULL    44000
```

I wrote this using self-join.

```
SELECT 
    A.ID
    ,A.NAME
    ,B.NAME
    ,A.SALARY 
FROM PROTRAC4 A
LEFT JOIN PROTRAC4 B ON A.MGRID = B.ID
ORDER BY A.MGRID ASC, SALARY DESC
```

He told me to use CTE as this improves performance. Is he correct? If yes, then how does a CTE improve performance? How can I use CTE in this case?

Comment: have you searched for examples of cte questions, as there are many on the site?

Comment: @Tanner, Yes and I have used CTE to remove duplicates and I am not an expert in using it.

Comment: This is a very typical recursive cte. There are hundreds if not thousands of examples just on SO. Hundreds of thousands of examples across the rest of the internet.

Comment: Probably he just wanted to see use of a CTE for hierarchy query (and for this see other questions as suggested above) and he wanted cumulative salary for each manager.  I don't think CTE always improve performance and I think that sometime, somepeople who discovered CTE, abuse of it.